# In iOS - Production and staging server included in single build

Tags: ios, configuration, xcode6, settings

I have an application having two servers STAGING and PRODUCTION. I used to release two builds with changing the servers in coding part. But now my client asked to provide a single build where we can provide an option in app settings or phone settings to chnage the URL.

I reserached a lot in stack overflow and came to know that at runtime when we select debug/release mode at the time of giving build, it can be possible but anyways it is also come under process of giving two builds.

I want to have a single build where the user can change the option of Staging/Producetion. Please help me. Is it possible. ?

Comment: You cannot switch between debug and release mode, but you can switch at runtime between two different base URL (or code paths) using any kind of configuration you can dream up. Think a Settings page with a switch.

Comment: May be diff. target can help here but you need to specify diff bundle identifier for temp. so user can install both target on same device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a switch somewhere in your application to turn on staging mode (switch off = production). The state of this switch is saved in NSUserDefaults. Then, depending to this state, you choose the right URL of server in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way -

1.In the sign in page depending upon the field you are using to enter the staging or production url ,open an UIAction sheet when the field(In my case i am using tableview cell, you can use a text field or a button) is clicked then show fields like below -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if(indexPath.row == 2) {
    [self showActionSheet];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
}
```

calling the action sheet above in the didselectrow which will open an action sheet as below

```
- (void)showActionSheet
{
NSString *actionSheetTitle = @"Choose Connection";
NSString *other1 = @"development";
NSString *other2 = @"staging";
NSString *other3 = @"production";
NSString *cancelTitle = @"Cancel";

UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:actionSheetTitle
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:other1, other2, other3, nil];

[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}


 - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
//Get the name of the current pressed button
NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"development"]) {

    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:nil forKey:@"UserId"];

    NSLog(@"Destructive pressed --> Delete Something");
}
if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"staging"]) {
    NSLog(@"Other 1 pressed");
}
if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"production"]) {
    NSLog(@"Other 2 pressed");
}

}
```

and finally saving the user state like above using NSUserDefaults like above in the clicked button index.